# Como utilizar TFDJSONDataSets no Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, json, delphi-xe4, firedac

## Explicação

Hoje eu estava vendo um exemplo chamado `FireDACJSONReflect` na pasta Samples do Delphi XE6 e eu vi que era muito interessante a forma que o servidor se comunicava com o cliente e eu gostaria de utilizar esse meio na minha aplicação utilizando `TFDMemTable` para popular os dados da minha `DBGrid`, e também vi que era a única maneira "direta" de realizar comunicação com minha `TIWDBGrid`(componente de DBGrid dos componentes IntraWeb(IW)).

### ** Minha aplicação é um servidor feito em [delphi-xe4](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe4) e um cliente feito em [delphi-xe6](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe6) **

## Problema

Todavia, minha aplicação não usa delphi xe4, por isso nao sei como fazer essa comunicação pelo fato que o delphi xe4 não possui o Data.FireDACJSONReflect para adicionar no `uses` por isso não tenho o objeto `TFDJSONDataSets` e aí que está meu problema...

- Tem como utilizar o `TFDJSONDataSets` no Delphi XE4?
- Tem como popular os dados do  `TFDMemTable` sem o uso do `TFDJSONDataSets`?

## Algum código

Aqui eu possuo algumas linhas de código que utilizadas em um servidor datasnap delphi xe6 funcionariam porem o meu está em xe4:

```
function TDSSMetodoFinanceiro.getCotacaoLista : TFDJSONDataSets;
var 
  FDQCotacaoLista : TADQuery;
begin
  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.create;
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.listAdd(result, FDQCotacaoLista);
end;
```

**E la vem a pergunta, porque eu quero que minha função retorne um `TFDJSONDataSet`?**

Isso é porque eu tenho um `TFDMemTable` na minha aplicação cliente no delphi xe6 e eu preciso popular ele com dados utilizando `.appendData` e isso **aparentemente** precisa de um `TFDJSONDataSet` para fazer isso (talvez exista outra forma e eu gostaria muito de saber caso exista, mas até o momento só conheço esta).

Comment: Cara, dei uma pesquisada e falei com um pessoal que manja de Delphi e, pelo que entendi, você só consegue fazer isso do XE5 em diante

Comment: Pois é, só que eu gostaria de uma solução alternativa para realizar a comunicação direta entre minha aplicação xe6 e o meu servidor xe4

Comment: Upgrade do seu datasnap para o XE5 em diante resolveria... o que é uma otima coisa...

Comment: O problema é que eu realmente não posso fazer isto @Daniloloko

Comment: Ninguém vai responder? os 150 pontos de reputação irão expirar...

Comment: @Bacco tá certo, infelizmente ninguém achou nada então ao menos vc trouxe um conteúdo existente pra ca(a resposta do soen)

Comment: @PauloRoberto vc ainda está com este problema pra resolver, ou resolveu de outra forma?

Comment: resolver de outra forma eu resolvi porém eu gostaria de fazer da forma que eu pedi acima...

Comment: @PauloRoberto como o mínimo é 100 pra poder por um bounty meu nessa, vou pensar num plano B pra vc nao perder todo o investimento.

Answer (score 5):

TFDJSONDatasets foi introduzido no XE6, infelizmente não há como usar no XE4.  talvez o caminho seja uma FDMemtable em vez disso.

Ha um [tutorial](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2013/12/23/using-fdmemtable-with-rest/) de XE5 que talvez sirva pro XE4.

Aqui tem um [exemplo](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jtembarcadero/2013/12/19/no-time-endlesss-possibilities-with-rest-for-vcl-and-fm/) usando `ClientDataset`, tente e veja se serve.